Split Excel .csv Into Separate .csv Files Based on Breaks in Incremented Values in a Column
I have .csv files (50,000+ rows long each) that contain data from a sensor. A "counter" column (integer) is output by the sensor that increments in values of 100 (does not start at 0 or 1 but at a value determined by a clock). Sometimes there are errors in the sensor that cause the counter to skip so that there is a break in the continual increase of the count by 100. When this happens, the date, time, and navigational information from the sensor outputs as null/blank for an irregular number of rows before streaming intact data again.
I would like to find a way to delete the entire rows where these columns are blank throughout the file and then split each group of rows where the continuous count is preserved into individual .csv files, ideally with a copy of the original headings of the master file at the top of each. If possible, it would be nice to have each output csv file retain the original master file name with a sequential number added to the end ("OriginalName-1.csv", "OriginalName-2.csv", etc.). Eventually I would like to have it so the user can simply run the VBA and then select input and output folders where there are multiple such .csv files for the code to iterate through.
I know there are a lot of moving parts there so if anyone can help with the whole process that would be great but if nothing else is there an elegant way to split the file by a break in the count?
I've included a screenshot of what the .csv looks like to provide an example of the data I'm working with. Sensitive information has been redacted in black. Before and after the blanks you can see how I would be left with a jump in the counter that could be used to split the groups of rows into individual files. So for example in the image below, the end of the first output file would be the row where "counter" is 320243 (before the break) and the beginning of the next output file would be the row where "counter" is 442243 (after the break).
Also, all of the files involved only ever have one spreadsheet per workbook.
Thank you very much in advance for any help you can offer!
Screenshot showing an example of a "break" in the data stream

tl;dr
For entire folders of .csv files I want to:

Have the user select input and output folders in  file explorer

In each .csv in the input folder:
a. Remove entire rows where certain columns are blank (date, time, lat, long)
b. Split the groups of rows where the "counter" column is an uninterrupted increment of 100 into their own .csv files while retaining the header row found in the master file at the top of each new .csv.

Output each new split .csv with the name of the parent/master file and a sequential number at the end (("OriginalName-1.csv", "OriginalName-2.csv", etc.)


I have found VBA solutions for some of the individual tasks in other posts and on youtube which can be altered to fit my needs such as those mentioned below.
-To prompt the user to choose input and output folders (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkFdCc78oFo):
-To delete entire rows where a column has a certain value or is blank (https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/delete-rows-cell-values/)
But it is unclear to me how to tie it all together in one Sub in a way that would run quickly and that would include the file splitting by breaks in the count. I'm thinking something along the lines of "If the difference between cell values A1 and A2 > 100, split file between them". I just don't know how to translate that into VBA.
I have also considered adding a column that recodes the breaks in the counts into numbered groups (discussed here: https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/17qudhl/how_do_i_write_a_macro_that_fills_cells_in_one/). That seems like it would be an unnecessary step although the output files could maybe be renamed based on that column.
Lastly, do these files need to be converted to .xlsx to do any of this or can they remain as .csv files throughout the entire process?
I am very inept with VBA so please excuse my ignorance in any of these areas. Again thank you for any insight you might have! If there is a simpler answer via another method like Python I'm open to that as well.
Edit: Below is the code that I have modified from other posts to try and achieve what I am going for. I'm still researching how to split the master .csv files in the selected folder by a discontinuation in the counter so I'm just not sure how to do that yet (see comment in code below for where I think it should go). I did my best on the indentation but any suggestions on formatting or content would be most welcome! Thanks again for your help, I will keep updating as I continue to work on this today.
Sub MagExCSVClean()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim InputFolderPathString As String
Dim InputFileString As String
Dim InputFolderDialog As FileDialog
Dim OutputFolderDialog As FileDialog
Dim OutputFolderPathString As String
Dim OutputFileString As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
On Error Resume Next

    'User chooses input folder
    Set InputFolderDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    InputFolderDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    InputFolderDialog.Title = "Select the folder containing the .csv files you would like to process."
    If InputFolderDialog.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    InputFolderPathString = InputFolderDialog.SelectedItems(1) & "\"

    'User chooses output folder
    Set OutputFolderDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    OutputFolderDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    OutputFolderDialog.Title = "Select the folder where you would like to save the cleaned .csv files."
    If OutputFolderDialog.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    OutputFolderPathString = OutputFolderDialog.SelectedItems(1) & "\"

    InputFileString = Dir(InputFolderPathString & "*.csv*")

    Do While InputFileString <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=InputFolderPathString & InputFileString)

        'This is where all of the iterative loops for each file go once current file in folder is open

        'This section deletes row where there are breaks in data
        'Clear any existing filters
        On Error Resume Next
        ws.ShowAllData
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Apply Filter.
        ws.Range(Cells.Address ).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=""

        'Delete Rows 
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ws.Range(Cells.Address).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        'Clear Filter
        On Error Resume Next
        ws.ShowAllData
        On Error GoTo 0

        'loop for creating new workbooks from breaks in count goes here

        'changed file is saved before the loop moves on to the next
        OutputFileString = OutputFolderPathString & Left(InputFileString, InStr(1, InputFileString, ".") - 1) & ".csv"
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=OutputFileString, FileFormat:=xlCSV
        wb.Close savechanges:=True
        InputFileString = Dir

'return settings to normal at end of sub
Loop
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Welcome to SO.
Please share the details of the code you tried and describe the issue you are encountering.

This is kind of a large request that could be many separate requests to build the script you need. I'll break down how I'd go about it in something that hopefully runs for you.
Option Explicit

Sub SplitDataByChunkAndSaveCSVs()


    '----------------------------------------------
    ' Saving worksheet data in memory as an array
    '----------------------------------------------
    ' First get all the details we need from the spreadsheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Get last row and last column
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lastCol As Long: lastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    ' Read the sheet into memory which will run super fast, but requires more setup and data juggling
    Dim data As Variant: data = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Value
    
    '----------------------------------------------
    ' Clean out the missing data
    '----------------------------------------------
    ' Here we can remove blank rows based on the **second column
    ' by not adding them to the new cleanData array
    Dim cleanData As Variant: ReDim cleanData(1 To lastRow, 1 To lastCol)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rowCount As Long: rowCount = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        If Not IsEmpty(data(i, 2)) Then
            For j = 1 To lastCol
                cleanData(rowCount, j) = data(i, j)
            Next j
            rowCount = rowCount + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' because the number of rows in cleanData should be less than regular data, we should redefine the dimensions
    ' I find it's easier to just create a new
     ' Resize the cleanData array by copying to a temporary array
    If rowCount > 1 Then
        ReDim tempData(1 To rowCount - 1, 1 To lastCol) ' Resize the temp array to fit the non-empty rows
        For i = 1 To rowCount - 1
            For j = 1 To lastCol
                tempData(i, j) = cleanData(i, j) ' Copy the data over
            Next j
        Next i
        cleanData = tempData ' Assign the temp array back to cleanData
    End If
    
    '----------------------------------------------
    ' Sort?
    '----------------------------------------------
    ' If not sorted, you would need to sort cleanData array by the first column (ascending)
    ' feel free to look up any simple quicksort algos

    '----------------------------------------------
    ' Break the cleanedArray into individual Chunks
    '----------------------------------------------
    ' we can determine the sizes of each chunks by looping through the cleanedData array
    ' which will save memory and make things run a little faster
    ' but involves a bit more code
    
    ' initialize some values
    ' We do a first pass to determine chunk sizes
    ' how many rows per csv (not including the header)
    Dim chunkSizes() As Long: ReDim chunkSizes(1 To UBound(cleanData, 1)) ' Temporary, will resize later
    chunkSizes(1) = 1
    
    ' what row of the cleanedData to start the next csv from
    Dim chunkStart() As Long: ReDim chunkStart(1 To UBound(cleanData, 1)) ' Temporary, will resize later
    chunkStart(1) = 2 ' after header
    
    ' keeping track of the number of chunks
    Dim chunkCount As Long
    chunkCount = 1
    
    ' now we loop through all of the rows in our cleanData
    ' and determine whenever the delta is no longer 100
    ' which will indicate starting a new chunk / csv file
    Dim delta As Long
    ' i = 3 so we don't subtract from the header
    For i = 3 To UBound(cleanData, 1)
        delta = cleanData(i, 1) - cleanData(i - 1, 1)
        If delta = 100 Then
            chunkSizes(chunkCount) = chunkSizes(chunkCount) + 1
        Else
            chunkCount = chunkCount + 1
            chunkStart(chunkCount) = i
            chunkSizes(chunkCount) = 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' now we can resize the chunkSizes and chunkStart arrays to actual numberof chunks
    ReDim Preserve chunkSizes(1 To chunkCount)
    ReDim Preserve chunkStart(1 To chunkCount)
    
    ' and now a second pass loop where we actually fill the chunks with data
    Dim chunks() As Variant ' Array to hold all chunks
    ReDim chunks(1 To chunkCount) ' This will hold each chunk as a Variant array
    
    Dim chunkArray As Variant ' Array to hold each chunk
    Dim chunkNumber As Long ' loop variable to indicate which element of chunks arrays
    For chunkNumber = 1 To chunkCount
        ' Allocate memory for each chunk as a 2D array
        ReDim chunkArray(1 To chunkSizes(chunkNumber), 1 To lastCol)
        
        ' Fill each chunk 2d array with data
        For i = 1 To chunkSizes(chunkNumber)
            For j = 1 To lastCol
                chunkArray(i, j) = cleanData(chunkStart(chunkNumber) + i - 1, j)
            Next j
        Next i
        
        ' Store the chunk in the chunks array
        chunks(chunkNumber) = chunkArray
    Next chunkNumber
    
    '------------------------------
    ' Choosing where to save csvs
    '------------------------------
    
    Dim savePath As String ' Path for saving CSVs
    Dim fd As FileDialog ' File dialog for selecting folder
    ' Prompt user to select a folder for saving CSV files
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    fd.Title = "Select Folder to Save <" & chunkCount & "> CSV Files" ' add in the chunkCount for fun
    If fd.Show = -1 Then
        savePath = fd.SelectedItems(1) ' Get the folder path
    Else
        MsgBox "No folder selected. Exiting..."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Ensure path ends with a backslash
    If Right(savePath, 1) <> "\" Then
        savePath = savePath & "\"
    End If
    

    '------------------------------
    ' Save each chunk as a CSV
    '------------------------------
    ' Store headers (first row of cleanData) that we will repeat
    Dim header As Variant
    header = Application.Index(cleanData, 1, 0) ' Get entire first row (headers)
    
    ' loop using a handy csv function
    For i = 1 To chunkCount
        SaveChunkToCSV savePath, "Chunk" & i, header, chunks(i)
    Next i

    
End Sub

'----------------------------------------
' Function that saves CSV files
'----------------------------------------
Sub SaveChunkToCSV(savePath As String, fileName As String, header As Variant, chunkData As Variant)

    ' Create full file path
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = savePath & fileName & ".csv"
    
    ' Get a free file number
    Dim fileNum As Integer
    fileNum = FreeFile
    
    ' Open the file for writing
    Open filePath For Output As fileNum
    
    ' Write the header (one line)
    Dim line As String
    line = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(header)), ",")
    Print #fileNum, line
    
    ' Write the chunk data
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(chunkData, 1)
        line = ""
        For j = 1 To UBound(chunkData, 2)
            line = line & chunkData(i, j)
            If j < UBound(chunkData, 2) Then
                line = line & ","
            End If
        Next j
        Print #fileNum, line
    Next i

    Close fileNum
End Sub

This should be lightning fast unless you have really large data.
It actually builds the chunks ready for creating the csvs BEFORE asking you where you want to save them.
Let me know if you have any questions.
